# What is wrong with my program for arduino sensor?

Tags: c++, arduino

I bought the this humitid/temperature sensor here:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10167

And I've read the Datasheed here:
http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/RHT03.pdf

I tried to use some basics programming from my c++ class, but I don't know what is the issue? It looks like the Data input from the sensor isn't sending anything.  On the Datasheet, I need to send an input signal of 5V( for 20-40ms), then wait for the sensor's response and store the incoming Bits. The sensors data is always 0. I don't get why.

```
/* Code for the RHT03 Sensor 8/5/12 */

int i=0;
int SensorVccPin = 13; 
int datapin = 7;
int bitcheck1;
int bitcheck2;
int temp[16];
int humidity[16];
int sensorcheck[8];

void setup()
{
  pinMode(SensorVccPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(datapin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // This is the STEP #1
  digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, HIGH);  
  delayMicroseconds(30);   
  digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, LOW);  
  /* NEED TO DO BIG NESTED IF STATEMENTS!!!!*/

  digitalRead(datapin); 

  if (digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)    // FIRST BIG IF
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2);   
    }

  while(digitalRead(datapin) == HIGH)
  {
      delayMicroseconds(2);   
  }

  // STEP #2
  for (int i = 0; i<16; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2); 
    }  

    delayMicroseconds(10);

    bitcheck1 = digitalRead(datapin);   // maybe store as an array
    delayMicroseconds(17);      // 50 sec pause  // 27us = 0 bit, 70us is 1 bit data
    delayMicroseconds(15); 
    bitcheck2 = digitalRead(datapin);

    if (bitcheck1==bitcheck2)
    {
       temp[i]=1;
       delayMicroseconds(28); 
    } else {
       temp[i]=0;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i<16; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2); 
    }  

    delayMicroseconds(10);
    bitcheck1 = digitalRead(datapin);   // maybe store as an array
    delayMicroseconds(17);      // 50 sec pause  // 27us = 0 bit, 70us is 1 bit data
    delayMicroseconds(15); 
    bitcheck2 = digitalRead(datapin);


    if (bitcheck1==bitcheck2)
    {
       humidity[i]=1;
       delayMicroseconds(28); 
    } else {
       humidity[i]=0;
    }
  }


  for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(datapin) == LOW)
    {
      delayMicroseconds(2); 
    }  

    delayMicroseconds(10);

    bitcheck1 = digitalRead(datapin);   // maybe store as an array
    delayMicroseconds(17);      // 50 sec pause  // 27us = 0 bit, 70us is 1 bit data
    delayMicroseconds(15); 
    bitcheck2 = digitalRead(datapin);

    if (bitcheck1==bitcheck2)
    {
       sensorcheck[i]=1;
       delayMicroseconds(28); 
    } else {
       sensorcheck[i]=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I read the datasheet correctly, all operations are on the same pin.  Are SensorVccPin and datapin physically connected to the same sensor pin?  Wouldn't it be simpler and less error prone if you used the same pin and switched its mode from output to input after the initial transition?

Comment: yes, It makes sense , but I don't understand something. There is a Vcc Pin and a Data pin on the sensor, I thought the Vcc has to "kind of send a pulse" of 20-40us and then read the data from the data pin , no?
Sorry, Im not mainly english and this is my second year in EE.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: No, Vcc is constant, the entire pulsetrain has to be applied to / read from the DATA pin (pin 2).

Answer (score 5):

The datasheet says;

> MCU will pull low data-bus and this process must beyond at least
>   1~10ms to ensure RHT03 could detect MCU's signal

Your code says;

```
digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(10);

digitalWrite(SensorVccPin, HIGH);
```

You seem to be delaying 10µs instead of 10ms.